# How to toggle pause/play audio with button click in Pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I find in Stackoverflow before but almost example working in  element.

Have any method toggle click play/pause when using Javascript?

HTML Code:

`<button id="music" class="play-song"></button>`

My JS code look like:

```
<script>
const elem = document.getElementById("music");
if (elem) {
elem.addEventListener ("click", playMusic, false);
}

function playMusic() {
  var musik= new Audio("/songs/1.mp3");
  musik.play();
  var current = this;
  if (current != elem) {
    elem.classList.remove('mute-audio');
  } else if (current.classList.contains('mute-audio') === true) {
    current.classList.remove('mute-audio');
  } else {
    current.classList.add('mute-audio');
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Create the`musik` variable outside of the `playMusic` function so it exists between button presses

Comment: @AndyRay, it not pause audio when I click button Play again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const elem = document.getElementById("music");
if (elem) {
elem.addEventListener ("click", playMusic, false);
}

var musik= new Audio("https://xomkey.com/wp-content/uploads/songs/xomkey-song.mp3");

function playMusic() {  
  if(musik.paused){
    musik.play();
    // do your other task
  } else {
    musik.pause();
    // do your other task
  }
  
}
```

```html
<button id="music" class="play-song">Play/Pause</button>
```

You can play and pause with this piece of code like toggle. For audio, there are many more interesting methods.

For your reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement